install python package dynamically via subprocess pip but still see import error
I have to dynamically install the package: paho-mqtt (which itself depends on typing-extensions) in remote machine(python 3.7) via:
import subprocess
import sys
try:
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt_client
except ImportError:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 'paho-mqtt'])
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 'typing-extensions==4.7.1'])
finally:
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt_client

the package can be seen installed correctly, but the final import still failed:
Collecting paho-mqtt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/cb/00451c3cf31790287768bb12c6bec834f5d292eaf3022afc88e14b8afc94/paho_mqtt-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: paho-mqtt
Successfully installed paho-mqtt-2.1.0
Collecting typing-extensions==4.7.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/6b/63cc3df74987c36fe26157ee12e09e8f9db4de771e0f3404263117e75b95/typing_extensions-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions
Successfully installed typing-extensions-4.7.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tt.py", line 10, in <module>
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho'

also tried call the pip one time to install both packages, still the same error:
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 'typing-extensions==4.7.1','paho-mqtt'])

any idea?

Use pyproject.toml (or legacy setup.py or etc) to declare your dependencies, and make your script installable.

As an aside, pip can install multiple packages in one go. "pip", "install", 'paho-mqtt', 'typing-extensions==4.7.1' (though if paho-mqtt depends on typing-extensions, probably switch the order!)

For the record, I can repro. I'm guessing this is a peculiarity of this particular package.

@tripleee i've updated the question by tried your suggestion of one pip call for 2 packages, still same error

and I've tested the case, that i firstly manually installed the typing-extensions but leave paho-mqtt not installed, and re-run the script, it works, does this dynamic way only for single package scenario?

Maybe try subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "show","paho"])

Yeah, I only pointed out an inefficiency, and I did say "as an aside". If I had reason to believe this would solve your problem, I'd submit it as an answer, not a comment.

@MarkSetchell you mean to use the pip show  to instead the pip install? but the show seems just to list the info of the package, I tried it in environment without those packages, i just show Package(s) not found

No, I meant to use pip show in addition, after pip install to see if pip thinks it installed both packages.
